# How to create partition mysql 8

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a table with partition with following way

```
create table transaction_demo
(
    trx_id bigint not null primary key,
    created_datetime  datetime
) partition by range (YEAR(created_datetime)) (
    partition p1 values less than (2019),
    partition p2 values less than (2020),
    partition p3 values less than (2021)
    );
```

But it is not working. I am getting following error

```
[2019-08-02 15:08:43] [HY000][1503] A PRIMARY KEY must include all columns in the table's partitioning function
[2019-08-02 15:08:43] [HY000][1503] A PRIMARY KEY must include all columns in the table's partitioning function
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then define primary key for each column which will be part of the partition.

```
CREATE TABLE transaction_demo (
        trx_id int NOT NULL,
        created_datetime datetime NOT NULL,
        other_column_1 int NULL,
        other_column_2 varchar(222) NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY(trx_id,created_datetime)
    )
        PARTITION BY RANGE( YEAR(created_datetime) )(
        PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (2019),
        PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN (2020),
        PARTITION p3 VALUES LESS THAN (2021)
    );
```

Comment: get the same error when try to add primary key after creating table

Comment: I can not put all column as part of the primary key